# Difference between @a="<C-r>0" and @a=@0

Tags: vim, vim-registers, vim-macros

I've the following text copied to the `"0` register

```
test
test
```

1. If I want to copy the content of the `"0` register to the `"a` register I do

   ```
   :let @a=@0
   ```

   Then, if I paste the content of `"a` register I obtain

   ```
   test
   test
   ```
2. Now, to paste the content of the `"0` register to the `"a` register I do

   ```
   :let @a="
   ```

   and then `<C-r>0`, and the result is this

   ```
   :let @a="test^Mtest^M"
   ```

   Then I paste the content of `"a` register (`"ap`) and I obtain

   ```
   test^Mtest^M
   ```

Why are the results not equal?

Specifically, why the newline characters are written literally and not interpreted in the second case?

Answer (score 1):

From `:help c_ctrl-r`:

> […] And characters that end the command line are inserted literally (`<Esc>`, `<CR>`, `<NL>`, `<C-C>`). […]

--- EDIT ---

`<C-r>0` *inserts* the content of `"0` as if you typed it. Since `"0` contains a `<CR>` (two, actually, but the second is irrelevant):

```
test<CR>
test<CR>
```

that `<CR>` would be typed just as you would have typed it, which would result in the command being executed before the typing is finished:

```
:let @a = "test<CR>
```

which would throw `E114` because of the missing `"`.

The compromise, here, is to insert a literal `^M` instead of typing `<CR>` to allow the command-line to be finished.

You don't have that problem with `:let @a = @0` because there is no typing and no I/O involved: it's just values being passed around.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! So there isn't a way to interpret this characters using this method, isn't it? Am I obliged to use :let @a = @0 ?

Comment: However I'm a little confused by the manual entry that you recalled. Why is specified "characters that end the command line" if is considered also the character ^M which is inside the text?

Comment: Sorry but cannot notice any differences. What did you edited? Your reply or my post?

Comment: @user515933, now it's up.

Comment: ahaha ok so I'm not totally dumb :) So, I read your edit and that's clarified my doubt about that manual entry. However I have another question (sorry if it wasn't clear by my post): is there a way to convert the character ^M to actual newline character? because when I paste the content of the `"a` register what I see is the exact text `test^Mtest^M` instead of the words test on two lines. Is there a way to actually interpret ^M as a newline character when I paste the content of the register `"a`?